# Creating Grouped bars in Matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, matplotlib, bar-chart

I have just started learning python and I am using the Titanic data set to practice

I am not able to create a grouped bar chart and it it giving me an error
'incompatible sizes: argument 'height' must be length 2 or scalar'

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv("Titanic/train.csv")

top_five = df.head(5)
print(top_five)
column_no = df.columns
print(column_no)

female_count = len([p for p in df["Sex"] if p == 'female'])
male_count = len([i for i in df["Sex"] if i == 'male'])

have_survived= len([m for m in df["Survived"] if m == 1])
not_survived = len([n for n in df["Survived"] if n == 0])


plt.bar([0],female_count, color ='b')
plt.bar([1],male_count,color = 'y')
plt.xticks([0+0.2,1+0.2],['females','males'])
plt.show()

plt.bar([0],not_survived, color ='r')
plt.bar([1],have_survived, color ='g')
plt.xticks([0+0.2,1+0.2],['not_survived','have_survived'])
plt.show()
```

it works fine until here and I get two individual charts

Instead i want one chart that displays bars for male and female and color code the bars based on survival.

This does not seem to work

```
N = 2
index = np.arange(N)
bar_width = 0.35

plt.bar(index, have_survived, bar_width, color ='b')
plt.bar(index + bar_width, not_survived, bar_width,color ='r',)

plt.xticks([0+0.2,1+0.2],['females','males'])
plt.legend()
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You can check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20159305/2901002) and add some sample data to your question.

Comment: I am using train.csv from here https://www.kaggle.com/c/titanic/data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about replacing your second block of code (the one that returns a `ValueError`) with this

```
bar_width = 0.35
tot_people_count = (female_count + male_count) * 1.0

plt.bar(0, female_count, bar_width, color ='b')
plt.bar(1, male_count, bar_width, color ='y',)

plt.bar(0, have_survived/tot_people_count*female_count, bar_width, color='r')
plt.bar(1, have_survived/tot_people_count*male_count, bar_width, color='g')

plt.xticks([0+0.2,1+0.2],['females','males'])

plt.legend(['female deceased', 'male deceased', 'female survivors', 'male survivors'],
           loc='best')
```

I get this bar graph as an output,

[image]

The reason for the error you get is that the `left` and `height` parameters of `plt.bar` must either have the same length as each other or one (or both) of them must be a scalar. That is why changing `index` in your code to the simple scalars `0` and `1` fixes the error.